# Ingresar 2 numeros y hallar la suma de los intermedios

Tags: java, netbeans

Necesito ingresar 2 números y sumar los números intermedios que sean múltiplos de 3 incluido los 2 números ingresados, pero no funciona con todos los numeros, la condicion if entra en conflicto cuando se inicia o se termina en un múltiplo de 3 y no obtengo un resultado correcto

```
int a;
int b;
int i;
int suma;

System.out.println("Ingrese el primer valor");
a=s.nextInt();
System.out.println("Ingrese el segundo valor");
b=s.nextInt();

suma=0;
i=a;

do{
    r=i%3;
    if(r==0){
        suma=suma+i;
    }
    i=i+1;
}while(i<=b);    

System.out.println("El total es "+suma);
```

Comment: Tienes que ser más específico que error manda, en que linea, que resultados son los deseados y cuáles no? y no uses los comentarios para complementar la pregunta, mejor edita la pregunta y explícalo ahí.

Comment: No veo donde falla, puedes decir que error te da?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo probe tu codigo con los casos:

1. Primer numero multiplo de 3, Segundo no:

   ```
   int num1 = 3;
   int num2 = 11;
   ```

Me da 18 (3 + 6 + 9)

2. Primero numero no es multiplo, Segundo si:

   ```
   int num1 = 1;
   int num2 = 9;
   ```

Me da 18 (3 + 6 + 9)

3. Los 2 numeros son multiplos de 3:

   ```
   int num1 = 3;
   int num2 = 12;
   ```

Me da 30 (3 + 6 + 9 +12)

4. Los 2 numeros no son multiplos:

   ```
   int num1 = 1;
   int num2 = 11;
   ```

Me da 18 (3 + 6 + 9)

**No toma en cuenta ningun numero si no es multiplo de 3, o sea que anda bien tu codigo.**

> 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54...